# Output from function not being saved into file

Tags: python

```
def scrapeWikiArticle(url):
    response = requests.get(
        url=url,
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
    print(title.text)
    
    allLinks = soup.find(id="bodyContent").find_all("a")
    random.shuffle(allLinks)
    linkToScrape = 0
    
    for link in allLinks:
        if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1: 
            continue
        linkToScrape = link
        break
    
    scrapeWikiArticle("https://en.wikipedia.org" + linkToScrape['href'])

output = scrapeWikiArticle("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    # Write the output of the function call to the file
    file.write(output)
```

I have the following code, standard output is being printed but when I try to save it as a file using the with statement, it does not print. I have auto indentation in VSC so everything looks to be correct. I also set the chmod for the directory to be 0777.

Comment: `scrapeWikiArticle` does not return anything, so `None` is being assigned to `output`

Comment: @Levan if I call scrapeWikiArticle there is stdout to the terminal but how would I 'redirect' the stdout to a file in this case?

Comment: Hi! What exacly do you want to scrap and save to the file? In this code you are calling a function without a return (returning null) and calling him self infinitely.

Comment: Hi @kithuto I tried to use return but I am most likely missing something, if you would care to look. https://pastecode.io/s/dmup33jh

Comment: Can you edit the question and describe what are you trying to scrap? What do you want in the output file? in this code you sen you are still calling a function ininitely and retuning a function. You need to return a string to write it to the output file

Comment: @kithuto I edited my question earlier. Basically the output of when I call the function scrapeWikiArticle which is a list I want to be saved in a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
sys.stdout = f
scrapeWikiArticle("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Eventually I used `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` to reset the standard output back to the console. The output of function `scrapeWikiArticle` will be written to output.txt in the current directory.